# Is there any difference between the 2016 and 2017 iPhone SE?

Tags: iphone

Other than storage size, is there any difference between the 16/64GB versions of the iPhone SE released in 2016 and the 32/128GB versions released in 2017?

I have the opportunity to purchase a 64GB 2016 iPhone SE for less than the cost of a 32GB 2017 one. Is there any reason to prefer the newer phone even though it has less storage?

Answer (score 3):

There are no differences apart from storage.

> Apple today introduced an iPhone SE with larger storage capacities of 32GB and 128GB of storage, doubling the capacity of the 16GB and 64GB models

> Other than a bump in built-in storage, the iPhone SE’s other features remain identical

<sup>http://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/3/21/14998660/apple-iphone-se-128gb-announced-pricing-release-date</sup>